# Writing the implementation for an operator method

Tags: c++, header, operator-overloading, addition, long-integer

So I have a LongInt class that will have new definition for the + and * operators.  The initialization in the header file looks like:

```
friend LongInt operator+(const LongInt& x, const LongInt& y);
friend LongInt operator*(const LongInt& x, const LongInt& y);
```

however in my implementation file, where I'm defining the methods found in the header, VS doesn't recognize the operator+ function or the operator* function as being listed in the header.  I'm using the code:

```
friend LongInt LongInt::operator+(const LongInt& x, const LongInt& y)
{

}
```

and

```
friend LongInt LongInt::operator*(const LongInt& x, const LongInt& y)
{

}
```

Any ideas as to why this code wont work when I'm trying to define the operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `friend` keyword is only used when declaring or defining the operator inside of a class; when declaring the operator as a `friend` inside of the class and defining it elsewhere, `friend` is only used on the declaration, not the definition. Also, functions declared as `friend` inside a class are in fact free functions in namespace scope, not class members. So, your definitions should look more like:

```
LongInt operator +(LongInt const& x, LongInt const& y) { /*...*/ }
LongInt operator *(LongInt const& x, LongInt const& y) { /*...*/ }
```

For further reading material, read over the following page: [C++ FAQ: Friends](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/friends)

Comment: I know how to use an operator, but I need to change what the operator does in order to suit the situation I'm going to use it in.  In this case I'll be adding two custom classes.

Comment: @Ctak : Your question only shows declarations, not definitions (which is where you would change what they do); and your question specifically says you're having trouble trying to call the operator. I.e., your question in no way reflects what you just said. What is your **real** question then?

Answer (score 0):

You're overriding an operator ... you "call" it using the operator:

```
LongInt foo;
LongInt bar;
LongInt foobar = foo + bar;
```